How to remove excess white space around 3D plot inside Manipulate?
How should I eliminate all the excess white space in the panel displaying the graphics from this Manipulate?
The display:

The source code:
Manipulate[
 Show[{
   (* axes *)
   Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.0035],
     Arrowheads[0.0325],
     Arrow[{origin, {mult (R + r), 0, 0}}], 
     Arrow[{origin, {0, mult (R + r), 0}}], 
     Arrow[{origin, {0, 0, mult 3 r}}]
     }],
   
   (* Big circle K *)
   ParametricPlot3D[
    {R Cos[\[Sigma]], R Sin[\[Sigma]], 0}, {\[Sigma], 0, 2 \[Pi]},
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.0075]]],
   
   (* small circle C *)
   ParametricPlot3D[{R + r Cos[\[Tau]], 0, r Sin[\[Tau]]}, {\[Tau], 0,
      2 \[Pi]},
    PlotStyle -> Blue],
   
   (* toral surface *)
   ParametricPlot3D[
    {X[\[Theta], \[Phi]], Y[\[Theta], \[Phi]], Z[\[Theta], \[Phi]]},
    {\[Theta], 0, \[Alpha]}, {\[Phi], 0, \[Beta]},
    Lighting -> "Neutral",
    PlotStyle -> 
     Directive[Opacity[0.35, Gray], Specularity[White, 10]]],
   
   (* rotate C through angle \[Alpha] round z-axis *)
   ParametricPlot3D[
    RotationTransform[\[Alpha], {0, 0, 1}][{R + r Cos[\[Tau]], 0, 
      r Sin[\[Tau]]}],
    {\[Tau], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Blue]
   },
  
  PlotRange -> pltRng,
  ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 0.65},
  Boxed -> False, Ticks -> None,
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> origin, AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.0035], 
  AxesLabel -> labelStyle /@ {"x", "y", "z"},
  ImageSize -> Scaled[0.7]
  ],
 
 {{\[Alpha], 0.001, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(max\)]\)"}, 
  0.001, 2 \[Pi], Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{\[Beta], \[Pi], 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(max\)]\)"}, \[Pi]/4, 2 \[Pi], 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r, 0.76, "r"}, 0.1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{R, 2.8, "R"}, 0.5, 4, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Initialization :> (labelStyle[txt_] := 
    Style[txt, FontFamily -> "Times", FontSlant -> "Italic", Bold, 20];
   X[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := (R + r Cos[\[Phi]]) Cos[\[Theta]];
   Y[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := (R + r Cos[\[Phi]]) Sin[\[Theta]];
   Z[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := r Sin[\[Phi]];
   origin = {0, 0, 0};
   mult = 1.35;
   pltRng = mult {{-R - r, R + r}, {-R - r, R + r}, {-3 r, 3 r}}),
 TrackedSymbols :> True
 ]


With Boxed -> True, it seems there is no excess space: The graphics can be rotated so that the box touches each of four edges of the bounding box of the graphics. You could zoom with something like ViewAngle -> 35 Degree. Is that the sort of fix that works for you? You might have to fiddle around to find an angle that works well.

Also, something like TrackedSymbols :> Manipulate makes using it the applet more pleasant.

@MichaelE2: I didn't bother yet to optimize, e.g., including moving the first block of code into an Initialization. What exactly does TrackedSymbols :> Manipulate do? How does it differ from TrackedSymbols :> True?

Well, if you want people to try out your code, it shouldn't be such a pain to use. :) My comment was to make it easy for others to help. TrackedSymbols :> Manipulate tracks the symbols declared in the controls of the Manipulate. I'd have to look up what TrackedSymbols -> True does. If it does the same thing, it's because I learned the other when V6 came out and just keep using it.

@MichaelE2: Pehaps your computer is significantly slower than mine? I ran the Manipulate withoug any annoying delay (just the expected temporary degradation of the image as sliders were being moed). Did something else happen?

It wasn't slow. It reevaluated the graphics when I tried to rotate them. So I could rotate it only one small angle at a time. The sliders worked fine, but I was exploring your complaint about the space around the plot.

You can also try the Manipulate option FrameMargins.  Choose a negative number.   Try FrameMargins->-100

Use SphericalRegion -> False as an option to Show.

I don't see any significant improvement with SphericalRegion -> False or with FrameMargins -> -100. But ViewAngle -> 35 Degree fixes the problem.

I reposted the code but now with 'Initialization' and 'TrackedSymbols' options set.
